# 1 Error needs fix - cannot make a static reference to the non static method

Tags: android

This is my first post and first venture onto a forum about Android Development.

I've been working on this small android app for the last week and half and have done about as much as possible without anyone's help so far via online tutorials.

I have a specific issue now which I have not been able to resolve and I've been reading and trying different things to get it working since 9 this morning, including searching and trying various answers to similar questions right here.

I have a main activity which has a row of buttons to bring in different fragments.

The fragments have a row of buttons which need to play a different sound each.

I have created a separate app to test that the fragment buttons and java is working but this Java does not work when used with my fragment in the main app. I really need someone to just show me exactly what I need to add to get it working.

I understand that there is a lot of inefficiency with everything else but I would just like to concentrate on this one problem first. I just want to get it working and then with time I can change code as I develop a better understanding of what is going on as I learn Java.

The fragments swap is working correctly. GuitarActivity.java/activity_guitar.xml correctly pulls in fragment_guitar_tune_01.xml. I just need the java for GuitarTune01Activity.java to now work with fragment_guitar_tune_01.xml

Please help.

Many thanks, Jo

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidapptest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidapptest.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidapptest.GuitarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_guitar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidapptest.BassActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bass" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidapptest.ChordsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chords" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.androidapptest.GuitarTune01Activity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_guitar.xml**

Row of buttons to change the fragment in framelayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_guitar_page"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.androidapptest.GuitarActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home_page_go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_home_define"
            android:onClick="GuitarActivity" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </View>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_general_define"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_general_define"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_general_define"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/maincontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**GuitarActivity.java**

This contains the code to pull in fragments by clicking the buttons in the above xml.

```
package com.example.androidapptest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GuitarActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

        TextView textMsg;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_guitar_tune_01, null);
            textMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String msg = bundle.getString(KEY_MSG_1);
                if (msg != null) {
                    textMsg.setText(msg);
                }
            }

            return view;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            textMsg.setText(msg);
        }

    }

    public static class MyFragment2 extends Fragment {

        TextView textMsg;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_guitar_tune_02, null);
            textMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String msg = bundle.getString(KEY_MSG_2);
                if (msg != null) {
                    textMsg.setText(msg);
                }
            }

            return view;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            textMsg.setText(msg);
        }

    }

    public static class MyFragment3 extends Fragment {

        TextView textMsg;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_guitar_tune_03, null);
            textMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String msg = bundle.getString(KEY_MSG_3);
                if (msg != null) {
                    textMsg.setText(msg);
                }
            }

            return view;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            textMsg.setText(msg);
        }

    }

    FrameLayout container;
    FragmentManager myFragmentManager;
    MyFragment1 myFragment1;
    MyFragment2 myFragment2;
    MyFragment3 myFragment3;
    final static String TAG_1 = "FRAGMENT_1";
    final static String TAG_2 = "FRAGMENT_2";
    final static String TAG_3 = "FRAGMENT_3";
    final static String KEY_MSG_1 = "FRAGMENT1_MSG";
    final static String KEY_MSG_2 = "FRAGMENT2_MSG";
    final static String KEY_MSG_3 = "FRAGMENT3_MSG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guitar);

        // Define home buttons
        Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_page_go);

        // Fragment container
        container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.maincontainer);

        // Buttons to change the fragment
        // Spinner menu should be used instead
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        // Home button sound
        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code to execute
                Intent myintent2 = new Intent(GuitarActivity.this,
                        HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(myintent2);

                // Play button sound
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.button);
                mp.start();

            }
        });

        // Fragment stuff

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                MyFragment1 fragment = (MyFragment1) myFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(TAG_1);

                if (fragment == null) {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(KEY_MSG_1, "Replace MyFragment1");
                    myFragment1.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer,
                            myFragment1, TAG_1);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                } else {

                    fragment.setMsg("MyFragment1 already loaded");
                }
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                MyFragment2 fragment = (MyFragment2) myFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(TAG_2);

                if (fragment == null) {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(KEY_MSG_2, "Replace MyFragment2");
                    myFragment2.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer,
                            myFragment2, TAG_2);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                } else {
                    fragment.setMsg("MyFragment2 already loaded");
                }
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                MyFragment3 fragment = (MyFragment3) myFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(TAG_3);

                if (fragment == null) {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(KEY_MSG_3, "Replace MyFragment3");
                    myFragment3.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer,
                            myFragment3, TAG_3);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                } else {
                    fragment.setMsg("MyFragment3 already loaded");
                }
            }
        });

        myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        myFragment1 = new MyFragment1();
        myFragment2 = new MyFragment2();
        myFragment3 = new MyFragment3();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // if's the first time created

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.maincontainer, myFragment1, TAG_1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        }

    }
```

**fragment_guitar_tune_01.xml**

This is the fragment with a row of buttons to play sounds.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.22"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    tools:context="com.example.androidapptest.GuitarTune01Activity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guitar_tune_frag_01"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_guitar_note1"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/button_general_define"
        android:text="@string/guitar_note_01" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_guitar_note2"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/button_general_define"
        android:text="@string/guitar_note_02" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_guitar_note3"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/button_general_define"
        android:text="@string/guitar_note_03" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**GuitarTune01Activity.java**

This java if for the fragment. It is to play a different sound for a row of buttons located in the fragment. This code does not work with the fragment but works when tested seperately.

```
package com.example.androidapptest;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GuitarTune01Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_guitar_tune_01);

        Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_guitar_note1);
        Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_guitar_note2);
        Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_guitar_note3);

        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Play button sound
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.guitar_e_standard_1_e);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Play button sound
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.guitar_e_standard_2_a);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Play button sound
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.guitar_e_standard_3_d);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**CHANGES**

I have made the change suggested and after correcting a few errors (putting view.findViewbyID) I only have one error left to correct before I can test it.

Error is on line: *MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),*

It says

*rename in file (ctrl+2, r)*

and

*cannot make a static reference to the non static method getapplicationcontext from the type contextwrapper*

Any suggestions? Thanks

```
public static class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

        TextView textMsg;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guitar_tune_01, null);
            textMsg = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);

            Button button7 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_guitar_note1);
            Button button8 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_guitar_note2);
            Button button9 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_guitar_note3);

            button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Play button sound
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.guitar_e_standard_1_e);
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Play button sound
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.guitar_e_standard_2_a);
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Play button sound
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.guitar_e_standard_3_d);
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if(bundle != null){
                String msg = bundle.getString(KEY_MSG_1);
                if(msg != null){
                    textMsg.setText(msg);
                }
            }

            return view;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg){
            textMsg.setText(msg);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit your question?

Comment: The Java for the fragment does not work. 'GuitarActivity.java' correctly pulls in the fragment 'fragment_guitar_tune_01.xml', but its java in 'GuitarTune01Activity.java' does not do anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok in your layout you need change this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
**android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.22"**
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="30dp" >
```

for:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
**android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="30dp" >
```

You are using AppCompat library (extends ActionBarActivity) you need use this theme in your Manifest File
Change this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

for:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Try it!!!

Comment: No sorry that hasn't fixed my problem.

The xml files are all working and my fragment is working. It's just the Java is not found by the fragment. A fragment is pulled inside activity_guitar.xml. This works. But the java for the fragment located in GuitarTune01Activity.java is not working. So I believe the problem lies in the Java of the fragment. Maybe the fragment java should be in put in GuitarActivity.java to work. Tried everything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's not a simple code problem here that we can simply point at and help you fix; it's more of a misunderstanding of the Android lifecycle objects:  fragments and activities are not interchangeable.  If you want to launch your `GuitarTune01Activity`, which is an `Activity` and not a `Fragment`, then you need to launch it, as an Activity, via an `Intent` from some code (e.g., a button) in one of your fragments.

If you want to be able to swap it in and out, as with a `Fragment`, then you will need to make it extend `Fragment` instead of `ActionBarActivity` and rewrite it accordingly.

Comment: I've not really misunderstood the difference. I know the difference. But I don't know how to make GuitarTune01Java work as a fragment. fragment_guitar_tune_01.xml is working as a fragment just fine. I really need some more detailed pointers of what I need to do with GuitarTune01Activity.java to make usable. Would it work better as part of GuitarActivity.java? when I tried combining it with the main activity it just crashes the app. Separate it does nothing. If I can't work this I will just move onto doing 40 separate activities. Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the logic contained in GuitarTune01Activity to provide the behavior behind `MyFragment1`.  If that's correct, I suggest you take all of the code from your `GuitarTune01Activity.onCreate` (after setContentView) and merge it into `MyFragment1.onCreateView` or `MyFragment1.onAttach`, and begin debugging from there.  This tutorial is a decent place to start: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Would I then delete the GuitarTune01Activity.java? I will get to work and report back.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and it has taken with only a few errors and now just one more error to fix. Please see bottom of original question for the code and error. Thanks

Comment: Your latest error is because your `MyFragment1` is a static class, and you can't reference the non-static method from there.  You'll probably want to move the fragment to the outer scope (its own class file) and remove the `static` modifier on the `class` declaration, and that should do it.  And yes, you'll have no need for your GuitarTune01Activity.java afterward and it can be safely deleted.

Comment: Any chance of a code example? been trying to fix this for a while now and it's over my head. Thanks

Comment: Take your `MyFragment1` class, move it into MyFragment1.java, and remove `static` from `static class` at the beginning of it.

Comment: Hey, I got it working. I left static and just replaced MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), with MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), working really well now and just had my first app working on a phone. Lots of work to do still. But I should progress well now. Cheers